# ogr2ogr - accomodate spaces in -select properties

Tags: gdal, shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have a geojson feature collection. Some of its features have spaces in their property names. I am attempting to use the `-select` argument to limit which properties are included in the output.

Is there a way to pass in property names that have spaces in them? On Ubuntu 18.04.3 I have tried:

```
ogr2ogr -select '"My Property"' -f 'Esri Shapefile' my-shp-dir my-fc.json
```

Which results in: `Error 1: Field "My not found in source layer`

I have also tried not quoting the spaced properties, and putting square brackets around them.

Is there a way to handle spaces in properties?

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: @user30184 Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: Maybe `'"My\ Property"'`?

Comment: @wfgeo no such luck: `ERROR 1: Field '"My\' not found in source layer.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with select, but you can use `-sql` instead of `-select` to reference a column/property with spaces in the name:

```
ogr2ogr -sql 'SELECT "My Property" FROM layername' -f 'Esri Shapefile' my-shp-dir my-fc.json
```